# Adding cab data to SharePoint on premise list

Tags: javascript, json, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

> ```
> The code below throws “item added” log but actual data is not posted to SharePoint list.
> I am using SharePoint 2016 on premise.
>
> There is no error shown on the console while debugging the code.
>
>
>
>
> ////<!DOCTYPE html>
> ////<html>
> <head>
>     <meta charset="utf-8" />
>     <title>CSV to SharePoint</title>
>     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
> </head>
> <body>
>
>     <label for="csvFileInput">
>         <strong>CSV File:</strong>
>     </label>
>     <input type="file" id="csvFileInput" accept=".csv">
>     <button onclick="processFile()">Process File</button>
>     
>     <div id="output"></div>
>
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>         
>         var requestDigest;
>
>         // Fetch Request Digest
>         $.ajax({
>             url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",
>             method: "POST",
>             headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
>             success: function(data) {
>                 requestDigest = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
>             },
>             error: function(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
>                 console.log(errorMessage);
>             }
>         });
>
>         function processFile() {
>             var files = document.getElementById('csvFileInput').files;
>             if (window.FileReader) {
>                 getAsText(files[0]);
>             } else {
>                 alert('FileReader is not supported in this browser.');
>             }
>         }
>
>         function getAsText(fileToRead) {
>             var reader = new FileReader();
>             reader.onload = loadHandler;
>             reader.onerror = errorHandler;
>             reader.readAsText(fileToRead);
>         }
>
>         function loadHandler(event) {
>             var csv = event.target.result;
>             processDataAsObj(csv);
>         }
>
>         function processDataAsObj(csv) {
>             var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
>             var lines = [];
>             var keys = allTextLines.shift().split(',');
>
>             while (allTextLines.length) {
>                 var arr = allTextLines.shift().split(',');
>                 var obj = {};
>                 for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
>                     obj[keys[i]] = arr[i];
>                 }
>                 lines.push(obj);
>             }
>
>             addToSharePointList(lines);
>         }
>
>         function errorHandler(evt) {
>             if (evt.target.error.name === "NotReadableError") {
>                 alert("Cannot read file!");
>             }
>         }
>
>         function addToSharePointList(dataArray) {
>             dataArray.forEach(function (item) {
>                 var itemData = {
>                     '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.YourListNameListItem' },
>                     'Column1': item['Column1'],
>                     'Column2': item['Column2']
>                 };
>
>                 $.ajax({
>                     url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('YourListName')/items",
>                     type: "POST",
>                     contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
>                     data: JSON.stringify(itemData),
>                     headers: {
>                         "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
>                         "X-RequestDigest": requestDigest
>                     },
>                     success: function (data) {
>                         console.log("Item added!");
>                     },
>                     error: function (data) {
>                         console.log("Error: " + data);
>                     }
>                 });
>             });
>         }
>     </script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Code has been successfully when tested on browser.

The code below throws “item added” log but actual data is not posted to SharePoint list.

I am using SharePoint 2016 on premise.

There is no error shown on the console while debugging the code.

The code below throws “item added” log but actual data is not posted to SharePoint list.

I am using SharePoint 2016 on premise.

There is no error shown on the console while debugging the code.

The code below throws “item added” log but actual data is not posted to SharePoint list.

I am using SharePoint 2016 on premise.

There is no error shown on the console while debugging the code.